# Nokia G10 Android kernel source code availability and GPL request procedure

Tags: gpl

I'm thinking about doing a LineageOS port for the Nokia G10. One part of doing the port is getting access to the Android kernel sources. Since the Android kernel is [GPL 2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html), HMD - the company behind the Nokia phone - is obligated to release it. So far I have not found the sources anywhere.

Because I have not found the sources, I have contacted the support. The first contact with the first level support by email showed that this topic is unknown. I have looked into my phone again and found in the device's "about section" the statement:

> This product includes open source software that is included under the GPL ... Please send a written request to:
> Source Code Requests, Legal Department, HMD Global Oy, Bertel Jungin aukio, 02600 Espoo, Finland. ...

Has someone experience with the process? Providing a postal address seems to me an indication that any request is actually unwanted. It seems that the goal is to make it as hard as possible when a link would be sufficient.

The GPL states:

> The source must be provided as machine-readable source code.

What should I expect here? E.g. would it be still acceptable to receive a CD (for which I have no reader anymore) or some magnetic tape (which I also cannot read)?

What quality can I expect from the source code? The GPL states:

> complete source code means all the source code for all modules it contains, plus any associated interface definition files, plus the scripts used to control compilation and installation of the executable.

Will it be an accessible compatible format or what are the options to obfuscate it? Or is my concern not reasoned?

How much can it cost? The GPL states:

> for a charge no more than your cost of physically performing source distribution

I would assume it is the physical media what is meant here. Can it be more? What are the limits?

The GPL does not define a maximum expected time until the request must be fulfilled. Will I have to wait for months?

What other institutions could assist me, if my request is ignored?

I'm based in Germany and HMD is in Finland. I'm mentioning this, if the place of the legislation matters. Some legislation might have wrong-headed interpretations about the GPL validity and the rights of software users.

Comment: There is nothing in the license that says they must provide the source code via internet download.  Until you have followed their instructions for receiving the source code, I don't believe you have any cause for raising a complaint.  Keep in mind also that SOME of the kernel source code may be licensed from some other source and NOT covered by the GPL.  As such, you will probably not receive it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: Is opensource.stackexchange.com also handling legal aspects? I would have thought this is the right place here because the main part is legal related to the GPL.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks, the license seems to be not well written here and should have insisted on a open accessible internet location to prevent possible avoidance strategies. How can I assure that my written request is not getting accidently "lost" and I will receive an answer?

Comment: @k_o_ This site is not to be used to ask for specific legal advice.

Comment: Just checked: Nokia G10 was released in 2011. Usually there is a timeout - you may have no right to be handed 10 year old source code - but no problem when released in 2011 as long as they sold at least one :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 Maybe it has the same name, but I'm referring to the 2021 model: https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_int/nokia-g-10/specs?sku=719901146681

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you ask

> How can I assure that my written request is not getting accidently "lost" and I will receive an answer?

Send the request by registered mail with proof of delivery.

> The GPL states:
>
> > The source must be provided as machine-readable source code.
>
> What should I expect here? E.g. would it be still acceptable to receive a CD (for which I have no reader anymore) or some magnetic tape (which I also cannot read)?

Who knows?  The only way to find out is to send a request and see how they respond.  If you are not satisfied with their response, you can consider hiring a lawyer and taking them to court.

I note that "machine readable" passports are so called because they are designed to be read by an optical scanner.  If they are serious about making it difficult to reuse their source code, it is entirely possible that they will send you a printed listing on the argument that it can be read with a scanner.

Comment: It _has_ to be machine readable - if it is sufficiently difficult then someone will read it and put the source code on their website where anyone can download it, just as revenge.